# Which adjective is better to describe 'weather' and 'climate' that they are neither cold nor hot?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adjectives

There are some adjectives which are used to describe weather, such as **hot, cold, wet, dry, fine, nice, etc.**

I think we can use **'mild'** (relatively warm for winter or cool for summer). Or we can use warm to describe relatively mild conditions in winter, or cool for summer.

My first question is:

Which adjective is better to refer to the weather that is neither hot nor cold regardless of season? And I want to know if we refer to the weather as **'... weather'** regardless of season, are we now talking about climate?

Considering the answer for the second part of the first question, here is the second question:

Which adjective is used to describe climate that is again neither hot nor cold?

And finally, can we use adjectives which are used to describe weather for climate?

Comment: Also relevant, [an **oceanic climate,** also known as a **maritime climate,** has cool or mild winters and does not have dry or hot summers.](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_climate)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, but how about weather? **'Mild** winter is OK I guess, but can I say **'mild weather'** or **'mild climate'**? My last question was about if we can use the adjectives which are used to describe weather/ climate for climate/ weather?

Comment: @deadrat Thanks for your answer.another question if you don't mind: Can we say **'temperate winter/summer'**?

Comment: Of course.  Google the phrase "temperate winter" to find examples.

Comment: @deadrat Great!

Comment: Great question. :-)

Comment: @deadrat - Temperate should definitely be a listed answer. It was my first thought.

Comment: @Charon This is a fascinating word, from the Latin *tempero*, to mix properly.  The Romans used it to describe climate the way we do.  We get *temperature*, the measure of a substance once the hot and cold in it have been mixed, as well as *temper* (a metal), *temperament* (mixture of feelings, where *proper* means restrained), and *temperamental* (which has somehow lost the restrained sense).  The google finds numerous examples of the use for both climate and weather.  Would you like to do the honors and post the answer?

Comment: @deadrat - Thank you sir, I shall. Before I do so however, I'll have a look at the etymology that you mentioned. It's very interesting. By the way, do you have a source, or is that all from your memory?

Comment: @Charon No, my memory of Latin vocabulary has faded over the last 40 years.  I check *Cassell's* Latin dictionary when I need to.  Online etymology sources are pretty good.  If I need more, I've got the print editions of the *OED*.  If there's anything you'd like me to look up for you, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scorning the unsupported answers given in the comments (although those may be correct, as far as they go, they're not complete), I'll suggest 'moderate':

> 2. Not violent or subject to extremes; mild or calm; temperate: *a moderate climate*.

[moderate. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved January 17 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moderate .]

For your questions 1-3, then,

1. If talking about 'moderate' weather, we're not necessarily talking about 'climate'.
2. 'Moderate'.
3. Yes.

Examples:

> 1. The *moderate* weather in Washington State does not often produce violent thunderstorms or tornados.
> 2. The *moderate* climate of the state is produced by the tempering influence of the warm North Pacific Drift. Temperature extremes are unusual as a result of that influence.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain if **'mild'** can be used in this case? For example: can we say mild weather/ climate. however, I'm not sure if **temperate**, as *deadrat* mentioned in comment,  is better or **moderate** as you suggested, thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @haha, Yes, you could say either mild weather or mild climate. However, you understand that weather and climate are distinct? As for 'temperate' or 'moderate', my feeling is that 'temperate' is used more often with reference to climate than weather; 'moderate' is, in my experience, used for both.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to these great answers,

[**Clement**:](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/clement)

Clement weather is neither too hot nor too cold. (Longman Dictionary)

> It is a very clement day. [(Oxford Dictionary)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clement)
>
> Hawaii is known for its delightfully clement climate. [(Merriam Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clement)
>
> The area is usually known for its clement weather. [(The Free Dictionary)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clement)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for some fancy synonym, you can also talk about the [Goldilocks](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/goldilocks?q=Goldilocks) climate, economy, weather, etc.

> without extremes; just right

```
The planet is in what astronomers call the Goldilocks zone: neither
too hot, nor too cold.

A return to the Goldilocks economy when growth was just right.
```

This is **the Goldilocks climate**, in a way. It's not too hot in the summer (warmest month mean temperature < 72° F), not too cold or too warm in winter (between 27 and 65° F), has at least four months with mean temperatures above 50° F, and has its dry season in the summer. We're talking Santa Barbara (3C), Portland (4C), and Seattle (4C).

> From the story Goldilocks and the three bears where a girl finds a
> house and tries things out until she finds the one that is just right:
> the chair that is neither too big nor too small, the porridge that is
> not too hot and not too cold, and the bed that is neither too hard nor
> too soft.

[image]

Source: The 2010-2011 Arlington/Fairfax Counties Northern Virginia Area Real Estate Guide by Mark G. Melikan Jr.

Comment: Thank you Faemu for your answer. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be a question on geography or meteorology. It's called temperate climate or warm climate.

Answer (score 0):

balmy weather.....means a pleasantly warm weather

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange! Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please add sources to support your answer.